# foreach pode substituir fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysqli

Vi em um vídeo que o cara pega a query e joga direto no foreach e consegue listar sem nenhum problema, minha dúvida é a seguinte: se realmente for possivel, usando apenas o foreach iria ser muito mais pratico do que usar while com fetch_array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dá pra fazer tudo de uma vez só com `foreach`, a questão é se realmente vale à pena.

Pra usar o `foreach` você precisaria obter os dados, seja com `mysqli_fetch_all` ou acumulando em algum lugar com várias leituras, o que é ruim em algumas situações porque de qualquer forma vai precisar pegar todos os dados e guardar na memória se quiser usar o `foreach`.

Para uma requisição ou um site pouco acessado, isso é irrelevante. Aliás, com poucos dados, o `mysqli_fetch_all` pode até ser mais "econômico". Para *queries* de grandes listagens em um site "concorrido", a coisa já muda de figura.

De acordo com o [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> *As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you will need a looping construct that will further impact performance. For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer for processing.*

Que, mais ou menos, é o seguinte:

> Como mysqli_fetch_all() retorna todas as linhas como *array* num passo só, pode consumir mais memória que funções similares como mysqli_fetch_array(), que só retorna uma linha por vez do set de resultados. Se você precisa iterar sobre os resultados, vai precisar de um loop que impacta a performance. Por essas razões, o mysqli_fetch_all() só deve ser usado onde o resultado precisa ser enviado para processamento em outra camada.

Vide exemplo de uso do `mysqli_fetch_all` [na resposta do colega @Inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142359/70)

Em outras palavras, o fato de usar `foreach` não dispensa uma série de `fetch_array`, `fetch_assoc` ou função que faça coisa similar, como mencionado.

Um jeito geralmente mais simples é usar `while` com `mysqli_fetch_row`ou `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, pois você normalmente vai usar os registros um a um e já liberar em seguida.

Veja um exemplo simples de uso do `while` com `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect( ... );

    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT name, country FROM city ORDER BY name') or die ("Erro na query: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['name'], $row['country']);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Tem exemplos parecidos no próprio site do PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o `mysqli_fetch_all()`, dessa forma fazer um `foreach` dos dados já obtidos.

Desta forma usando:

```
$sql = mysqli_connect(...);

$Select = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT id, nome, idade FROM tabela WHERE 1 = 1');

$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($Select, MYSQLI_NUM);

if(!!$resultado){
    foreach($resultado as list($id, $nome, $idade)){

      echo 'id>'.$id;
      echo 'nome>'.$nome;
      echo 'idade>'.$idade;
      echo '<br>';

    }
}
```

Nesse caso eu usei o `list()` para que cada item do `SELECT` tenha uma variavel exclusiva, isso permite que o código fique mais limpo e sem ter que usar, por exemplo: `$item['id']`, `$item['nome']`, `$item['idade']`.

Entretanto pode fazer isso, tranquilamente:

```
//...

$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($Select, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(!!$resultado){
    foreach($resultado as $item){

      echo 'id>'.$item['id'];
      echo 'nome>'.$item['nome'];
      echo 'idade>'.$item['idade'];
      echo '<br>';

    }
}
```

Nesse caso terá que usar o `MYSQLI_ASSOC` ao invés do `MYSQLI_NUM`. A diferença entre eles é que o primeiro retornará uma array cujo os índices possuem o nome da coluna, enquanto o segundo é somente número. Em exemplo, o primeiro poderá obter usando `$item['id']`, no segundo deveria de usar `$item['0']`.

Você pode ler mais na documentação em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php.

### **Diferença entre o `mysqli_fetch_all()` e `mysqli_fetch_array()`:**

Em relação a performance, é extremamente relativo.

O manual do PHP afirma que pode haver maior uso de memoria, como mencionado pelo [@Bacco em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142356/15089). Porém na própria documentação do PHP [um usuário relatou que isso não ocorre](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#116673), pessoalmente nunca notei diferenças entre os dois, hoje em dia utilizo o `mysqli_fetch_all`, *mas não por questão de performance.*

> Nota: O `mysqli_fetch_all()` utiliza o `mysqlnd`, é necessário que utilize-o. Isso é por padrão é instalado em PHP 5.4 e superiores, salvo engano.
>   
>   Caso não tenha o mysqlnd desinstale o `mysql` (`yum remove php-mysql`) e instale o `mysqlnd` (`yum install php-mysqlnd`). :D

Olhando no código-fonte do mysqlnd conseguimos encontrar isso na linha `1806`, [veja isso clicando aqui](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_result.c#L1806).

```
/* {{{ mysqlnd_res::fetch_all */
static void
MYSQLND_METHOD(mysqlnd_res, fetch_all)(MYSQLND_RES * result, const unsigned int flags, zval *return_value ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC)
{
    zval  row;
    zend_ulong i = 0;
    MYSQLND_RES_BUFFERED *set = result->stored_data;

    DBG_ENTER("mysqlnd_res::fetch_all");

    if ((!result->unbuf && !set)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "fetch_all can be used only with buffered sets");
        if (result->conn) {
            SET_CLIENT_ERROR(result->conn->error_info, CR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, UNKNOWN_SQLSTATE, "fetch_all can be used only with buffered sets");
        }
        RETVAL_NULL();
        DBG_VOID_RETURN;
    }

    /* 4 is a magic value. The cast is safe, if larger then the array will be later extended - no big deal :) */
    array_init_size(return_value, set? (unsigned int) set->row_count : 4);

    do {
        mysqlnd_fetch_into(result, flags, &row, MYSQLND_MYSQLI);
        if (Z_TYPE(row) != IS_ARRAY) {
            zval_ptr_dtor(&row);
            break;
        }
        add_index_zval(return_value, i++, &row);
    } while (1);

    DBG_VOID_RETURN;
}
/* }}} */
```

Aparentemente ele executa um loop, então entrega todos os dados. Portanto, **utilizar o `foreach` você estaria fazendo dois loops**! Um primeiro foi feito pela biblioteca do `mysqlnd` ao realizar o `mysqli_fetch_all()` e um segundo que é o `foreach`, que seu próprio código está executando. Isso supostamente poderia causar perda de desempenho, alem de obviamente maior uso de memoria. :S